# Why do I get a syntax error about INSERT INTO?

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem running my Visual Basic app. I get `syntax error INSERT INTO` when I try to add data into my DataGridView.

Here is the code below, can you tell me what is wrong with it?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection if it is not already opened
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    'new connection
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    'check whether to add new or update
    If Me.txtEmployeeID.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'add new 
        'add new data to table
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Attendance(EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Date, Holiday, HalfDay, Other, Sick, UnpaidHoliday, DaysTaken, DateFrom, DateTo) " & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.txtEmployeeID.Text & ",'" & Me.txtFirstName.Text & "','" & Me.txtLastName.Text & "','" & Me.txtdate.Text & "','" & Me.txtHoliday.Text & "','" & Me.txtHalfDay.Text & "','" & Me.txtOther.Text & "','" & Me.txtSick.Text & "','" & _
        Me.txtUnpaidHoliday.Text & "','" & Me.txtDaysTaken.Text & "','" & _
        Me.DateTimePicker2.Text & "','" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        'update data in table and execute
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Attendance" & _
            " SET EmployeeID =" & Me.txtEmployeeID.Text & _
            ", FirstName ='" & Me.txtFirstName.Text & "'" & _
            ", LastName ='" & Me.txtLastName.Text & "'" & _
            ", Date ='" & Me.txtdate.Text & "'" & _
            ", Holiday ='" & Me.txtHoliday.Text & "'" & _
            ", HalfDay='" & Me.txtHalfDay.Text & "'" & _
            ", Other='" & Me.txtOther.Text & "'" & _
            ", Unpaidholiday='" & Me.txtUnpaidHoliday.Text & "'" & _
            ", DaysTaken='" & Me.txtDaysTaken.Text & "'" & _
            ", DateFrom='" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Text & "'" & _
            ", DateTo='" & Me.DateTimePicker2.Text & "'" & _
            " WHERE employeeID =" & Me.txtEmployeeID.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    'refresh data in table list
    refreshdata()
    'clear form
    Me.btnclear.PerformClick()
    'close connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: you very likely have an unmatched number of ticks.  use parameter for your queries and that wont happen and the bigger problem of SQL injection is avoided.  You are also doing some type conversions you dont really want too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the Word DATE that in many databases is a reserved keyword. You should enclose it in square brackets

```
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Attendance(EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, [Date], " & _
                    "Holiday, HalfDay, Other, Sick, UnpaidHoliday, DaysTaken, DateFrom, " & _
                    "DateTo) " .......
```

But you have a bigger problem here. Concatenating string to form an sql command text is the perfect recipe for disasters. Sql Injections and parsing problems are here waiting for your command. Use always a parameterized query

So, just as an example

```
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Attendance(EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, [Date], " & _
                    "Holiday, HalfDay, Other, Sick, UnpaidHoliday, DaysTaken, DateFrom, " & _
                    "DateTo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Me.txtEmployeeID.Text)
  ..... and so on for the other eleven parameters.....
  ..... add them in the exact order in which they appear in the parameter list ....
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Don't forget to update your code to use parameters. Apart from Sql Injection what do you think will happen if the Me.txtLastName.Text contains a name with a single quote? `O'Brian` for example....

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is a reserved word in T-SQL, so you will need to add square brackets around it:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Attendance(EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, [Date], Holiday, HalfDay, Other, Sick, UnpaidHoliday, DaysTaken, DateFrom, DateTo) " & _
            " VALUES(" & Me.txtEmployeeID.Text & ",'" & Me.txtFirstName.Text & "','" & Me.txtLastName.Text & "','" & Me.txtdate.Text & "','" & Me.txtHoliday.Text & "','" & Me.txtHalfDay.Text & "','" & Me.txtOther.Text & "','" & Me.txtSick.Text & "','" & _
            Me.txtUnpaidHoliday.Text & "','" & Me.txtDaysTaken.Text & "','" & _
            Me.DateTimePicker2.Text & "','" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Text & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? If EmployeeID is Identity Column you can not insert value explicitly into it.